# attach to process - visual studio 2010 - windows 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, attach-to-process

I have a web page running on localhost that I want to use to break-point in code in Visual Studio 2010.  The web page is running in Internet Explorer.  The OS is Windows 2008.  When I go to attach to process under the debug menu in Visual Studio, the process w3wp.exe is not listed.  The web page is being hosted on the same machine that I am using to develop.  Shouldn't w3wp.exe be listed in the processes in Windows 2008 when a web page is running?  Attaching to the Internet Explorer process doesn't work.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Visual Studio as an administrator?  It's possible that the w3wp.exe process is running with different credentials than your user account.  If that is the case then you won't be able to attach to the process and will have to run Visual Studio as an administrator in order to debug

Comment: One of the  things that I found was that the process seems to stop if it is not used periodically.  I was trying to connect to it and not using it although I had opened a page I think it got stale.  Also, I checked on show processes from other sessions in the connection dialog and w3wp appeared then.  Thanks for your reply!